# Problem with C# Web API export excel file that can not open the file because file format or file extension is not valid

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to generate excel file from my database and download the file from my website but when I open the excel file the error "can not open the file because file format or file extension is not valid." has occurred. 
So, This is my code for doing this.

Here is my script:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnExportExcel").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const deferred = $.Deferred();
        var paymentType = $("#transactionTypeDropdown").val();
        var paymentStatus = $("#paymentStatusDropdown").val();
        var merchantName = $("#merchantNameDropdown").val();
        var dateTime = $("#reservation").val().split(" ");
        var refNo = $("#refNoInput").val();
        var terminalId = $("#terminalID").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            crossOrigin: true,
            url: "/api/Transaction/ExportExcel",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
            },
            data: {
                "Date_1": dateTime[0],
                "Date_2": dateTime[2],
                "PaymentType": paymentType,
                "Status": paymentStatus,
                "Outtrade": refNo,
                "Merchant": merchantName,
                "TerminalID": terminalId
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (dateTime[0] == dateTime[2]) {
                    filename = "Transaction_Detail_" + dateTime[0].replace(/\//g, '-') + ".xlsx";
                }
                else {
                    filename = "Transaction_Detail_" + dateTime[0].replace(/\//g, '-') + " - "
                        + dateTime[2].replace(/\//g, '-') + ".xlsx";
                }

                var uri = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,' + result;
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                link.href = uri;
                link.style = "visibility:hidden";
                link.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                getErrorMessage(jqXHR, exception);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    });
});
```

Here is my C# API:

```
public class TransactionController : ApiController
{        
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Transaction/ExportExcel")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ExportExcel(TransactionSearchReq req)
        {
            TransactionMgr transaction = new TransactionMgr();
            List<TransactionRecordRes> transactionList = new List<TransactionRecordRes>();
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            byte[] fileContents;
            string fileName;
            try
            {
                // Get transaction records
                transactionList = transaction.GetSearchTransactionRecord(req);
                if (transactionList.Count() > 0)
                {
                    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
                    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
                    {
                        var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

                        // I put data to worksheet here.

                        fileContents = package.GetAsByteArray();
                    }

                    if (fileContents == null || fileContents.Length == 0)
                    {
                        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                        response.Content = new StringContent("Export file error.", Encoding.Unicode);
                        return response;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (string.Compare(req.Date_1, req.Date_2) == 0)
                        {
                            fileName = string.Format("Transaction_Detail_{0}.xlsx", req.Date_1.Replace('/', '-'));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fileName = string.Format("Transaction_Detail_{0} - {1}.xlsx", req.Date_1.Replace('/', '-'), req.Date_2.Replace('/', '-'));
                        }

                        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileContents);
                        response.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
                        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = mediaType;
                        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                            new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = fileName };
                        return response;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                    response.Content = new StringContent("Export file error.", Encoding.Unicode);
                    return response;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                response.Content = new StringContent("Export file error.", Encoding.Unicode);
                return response;
            }
        }
}
```

Where I'm going wrong ?

Comment: Can you download a file and attach an example to this question (an actual real payload that you served up)?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills Here is the example excel file. [link](https://workupload.com/file/tGYUFSA5)